# Can anyone identify why this incrementer is losing count?

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, debounce

I am working on a project where the end result is to count the number of cycles of a moving piece of metal using an inductive sensor.

For now I am using an Arduino Uno and have created a breadboard version for testing. The sensor has been replaced by a momentary push button. To check the count data I am viewing the number using Serial Monitor

All the elements of this set-up are working, apart from one major issue. When pressing the button the incrementer (++) occasionally adds 2 instead of 1 from only one button press. As a rough guide to the error frequency, it seems to count 11 for every 10 button presses. The error has never presented as not counting enough.

I am new to software, as such I cannot seem to see the error

Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated

Here is the code I have written so far:

```C++
//Libraries
#include <EEPROM.h>

//Constants
const int counterPin = 2;   //Input from counter (looking for HIGH as external pulldown resistor is used)
const int EEPROMadress = 3; //holds the EEPROM address

//Variables
int counterState = 0;       //current button state
int counterStatePrv = 0;    //previous button state
int storedValue;            
int presetCount = 100;

unsigned long countNumber;      //unsigned 32bit variable

void setup() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
        // this performs as EEPROM.write(i, i)
        EEPROM.update(i, i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
        // write "presetCount" value to cell "EEPROMaddress" only the first time
        // will not write the cell the remaining 254 times
        EEPROM.update(EEPROMadress, presetCount);
    }

    pinMode(counterState, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);

    countNumber = EEPROM.read(3);   //Start the counter at the presetCount value
}

void loop() {

    counterState = digitalRead(counterPin);   //Read the status of the counter input
    storedValue = EEPROM.read(EEPROMadress);

    if (counterState != counterStatePrv) {      //check that pulse went off
        if (counterState == HIGH) {             //check for pulse
            countNumber++;                      //increment (add 1) to the stored count value
            delay(10);
            Serial.print("Count  Value: ");
            Serial.println(countNumber);

            Serial.print("Stored Value: ");
            Serial.println(storedValue);
            Serial.println();

        }
    }
    counterStatePrv = counterState;

}
```

Comment: You need to debounce the button.

Comment: Are you sure you are not writing too much into the EEPROM?

Comment: How is it wired? Is there a pull-down resistor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons bounce (at least they appear to, electrically), meaning that if you're fast enough, you can detect multiple pulses per button-press. Usually we don't count the button as being pressed until we read the same value {n} times in a row or for {m} mSec, or some similar technique.

Because you call `EEPROM.read()` immediately after testing the button, perhaps most times the bouncing will have ceased when the call returns, but once in a while one last bounce slips through.

Nick Gammon, a regular contributer here, has a good discussion of [de-bouncing](http://www.gammon.com.au/switches) on his web site. Have a look at that and pick a technique that's compatible with what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Nick Gammon your website was very helpful. I have now added the debounce and the count is tracking correctly. Thanks all